# "Change" or "changes"?

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number

Say you corrected a few typos and grammar issues.

Is that considered as one change? Or several changes?

Would you say "I like my change to the story" or "I like my changes to the story"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the corrections are a part of a larger purpose, or a series of steps to one end- the singular form is appropriate. However, several unconnected changes or corrections shall use the plural form of the word.

Comment: +1 Made me delete my answer :-)